# SonarQube 4.5.1 cannot start - unable to locate class org.sonar.application.StartServer

Tags: java, wrapper, classnotfoundexception, sonarqube

I have trouble with running new SonarQube. The log is as follows:

```
OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)
OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
 Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.StartServer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.application.StartServer

WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]

Where:
 app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
 app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
              application.
 <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

wrapper.conf:

`wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=160m
wrapper.java.additional.3=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djruby.management.enabled=false
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Xmx1024M
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mysql/.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.5=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/postgresql/.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.6=../../extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql/.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.7=../../conf
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=256
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.StartServer
wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.log
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE
wrapper.console.title=SonarQube
wrapper.single_invocation=true
wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=240
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=3000`

sonar.properties:

`sonar.jdbc.username=*
sonar.jdbc.password=*
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
sonar.web.context=
sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.notifications.delay=60`

java -version:

`C:>java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way Fabrice is right, instead of trying to update the old Sonar I've installed it from scratch and connected it to existing database. However the wrapper.config was not the source of the problem since it is the same right now and running just fine. 
Anyway, fresh installation helped me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Learn to read:
"However the wrapper.config was not the source of the problem since it is the same right now and running just fine"

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is definitely broken. If you read the ["Release 4.5 Upgrade Notes"](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.5+Upgrade+Notes) or the up-to-date ["Installing" documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing), you will notice that no configuration should be done in the `wrapper.conf` file - except the location of the Java executable if required.

I therefore suggest that you restart your install from scratch, following the install documentation.

Comment: I need to disagree a bit. From the same wiki about upgrading Sonar (which is what I've  done) http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading

"Update the content of the sonar.properties and wrapper.conf files located in the NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf directory with the content of the related files in the OLD_SONARQUBE_HOME/conf directory (web server URL, database settings, etc.). "
This is a quote saying to upgrade it with content of old files, which is exactly what I did.

Right now Sonar is up and running with this exact same wrapper config without any problems.

Comment: Yes, but during the migration to 4.5, the content of those files have changed which is clearly stated on http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.5+Upgrade+Notes

Comment: Still, it does not affect anything in my case. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Update jdk version from 1.7 to 1.8